# how to implement a local project to the other local project which have this specific directory structure and without converting it to binaries

Tags: java, gradle, directory

inside of this "root-project" it had this subproject "driver". How should we implement this rootproject to the subproject locally and not binaries?

```
:/root-project/
│   build.gradle.kts
│   gradle.properties
│   gradlew
│   gradlew.bat
│   settings.gradle.kts
├───.gradle
├───driver
├───gradle
└───src
```

subproject "driver" depends on "root-project". is there a way?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow  As far as I understood you, you want `root-project` to depend on the `driver` sub-module. Is this correct?

Comment: um hello @thokuest, yes and needed this root-project not as a binary but as a direct dependency so that I've never always publish it all over again. Do we need a "settings.gradle" inside of the subproject "driver"? is there any other way? thks in adv!